# create SQL Server agent job remotely by script

Tags: sql-server, sql-agent, sql-agent-job

Is it possible to create a SQL server agent job on a remote machine by scripts ? Any idea ..

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153.aspx) reference for the steps and the stored procs to call to do this.  As long as you can connect to the instance, and you have the necessary permissions you should be fine with doing this.